# How does Ubuntu handle looking at a Windows Raid?

Tags: nautilus, windows-7, raid, dmraid

If I install Ubuntu on hard drive A and mount (via nautilus) hard drive B that has Windows 7 installed on it with a RAID1, could Ubuntu even remotely screw up the RAID Controller? Or would it look at it like a normal single hard drive not in RAID?

I believe the RAID 1 is FakeRAID since I don't have a hardware raid controller card.

I can't afford to risk losing the RAID1 setup so I'm just double checking. ^^

-Thanks

Comment: You can add such additional info to your original question, that's easier to get a complete overview than burying it inside comments...  :)

Comment: No answers? Maybe I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, I can't tell if you've used up your Fake RAID volumes free space. If you haven't then you could add an additional partition in the Ubuntu installer which does support fakeraid. If Ubuntu is already up the  just:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dmraid
sudo reboot
```

and the fake raid volume should be present in `/dev/mapper`

Answer (score 2):

It could be "fakeraid" or Windows software raid.

I think that *if* Ubuntu recognizes your Windows partition (meaning it's fakeraid with an onboard controller supported by the kernel), then it should be safe to use it.  If the RAID is not recognized (and thus the Windows partition isn't seen), I wouldn't try to use it...